Do the C compilers preallocate every variable that exists in a program? Or do they allocate while the program is running?
For example, when I define a variable, like int x = 20; in a function that can possibly be called in main, does the compiler already allocates stack memory for that variable? 'Cause, as I said, it's a variable that may be called, but also may not be called and the program could possibly end and never call it.
I'm studying dynamic memory allocation and use cases of malloc and Ive been reading some stuff that led me to pure confusion lol

I'm studying dynamic memory allocation Stack variables are not dynamically allocated.

The C standard permits compilers to do anything that a program cannot detect. Since the function is never called, you cannot detect the existence of its variables, so the compiler is permitted (but not required) to remove it entirely.

The memory needed by x is pushed onto the stack every time the function is called (or 0 times if the function is never called, of course).
This happens at runtime, the compiler doesn't reserve/pre-allocate memory. If it turns out you don't have enough memory, you get a stack overflow, or out of memory error.

People can give you answers and explanations but honestly I think the only way for you to achieve actual clarity about how this works is to go and learn a little bit of assembly.

Are you aware of recursion? When you call function foo from within foo how would you preallocate the memory for each nested call of that function? You need a separate int x for each of the nested calls.

Unless you actually assign a different value to x inside your function then the compiler is within its rights to simply load that constant value of 20 whenever x is used. Even if you do change the value of x the optimiser can still choose to keep the variable in a register and never write it to memory.  This tends to happen with heavily used loop variables and a handful of frequently accessed variables. Such aggressive optimisation features are typically disabled in debug modes where all variables are explicitly written back to and loaded from memory.

@tkausl Re "Stack variables are not dynamically allocated.", The OP never said stack vars are dynamically allocated.  But they are. They are indeed allocated and de-allocated at run-time. These allocations and de-allocations happen automatically, which is why they are said to be in automatic storage. But it's still dynamically allocated.

Stack variables are most certinally dynamically allocated, the esp register is decreased to make room for the value on x86 32bit

int x = 20; tells the compiler to use 20 for x. That's it. Note I didn't mention memory at all. In fact, the following two programs are 100% equivalent:
printf( "%d\n", 20 );

int x = 20;
printf( "%d\n", x );

As long as it prints 20␊, the details of how it does it are not defined.

But let's say it does create a variable on the stack.

does the compiler already allocates stack memory for that variable?

No. The whole point of using a stack is to provide temporary memory. And to allow recursion.

A compiler can do all manner of optimization to remove extra variable declarations or allocate room for them in registers. Otherwise, in terms of stack allocation, it always happens in run-time because the compiler can normally not tell in advance how many times a function is called.
For some reason, bad learning materials tend to dumb down variable allocation and only speak of "stack vs heap" and ignore everything else. Check out What gets allocated on the stack and the heap?

Generally speaking, any local variables defined in a function are created at the time the function is entered, i.e. space is set aside on the stack for those variables, then the space is reclaimed when the function returns.
An important case here is recursion, where a function can call itself (either directly or indirectly).  In this case there's an instance of that function's local variables for each invocation of the function.  Because of this, there's no way to preallocate "all" variables.
Note also that the use of a stack is an implementation detail and not required by the C standard.  Also, compiler optimizations might not actually set aiside space at depending on how the variable is used.

The C standard doesn't deal with the storage of variables. The standard doesn't tell how variables are stored. The standard only specify "storage duration" which is defined as "life time", (quote) " storage is
guaranteed to be reserved for it."
The standard defines these types of storage:
static, thread, automatic, and allocated
The standard sets the rule (aka life time) of each of these but it does not tell how/where they are stored. That's up to the implementation (i.e. compiler for the specific processor/OS).
The typical way is that "static/global variables" are allocated in a special memory area at start up (data segment/BSS).
int x;  // <--- allocated at startup and availble as long as the program runs
int main(void) {
    ....
}

Memory for "automatic variables" are typically reserved when the program execution evaluates the definition. Typically on a stack.
void foo(void) {
    int x;  // <--- Memory "reserved" at run time. Typically on a stack
    ...
} // <--- Now the life time of X ends

Memory for "allocated variables" is also at run time and comes from a call to malloc, calloc, realloc. They are typically allocated in a memory area called the heap. The life time is until you explicit call free. Example:
char* foo(void) {
   char* p = malloc(SOME_SIZE);  // <--- In the absent of error the life time starts here
   return p;
}

void bar(char* p) {
    free(p); // The life time of p ends here
}

// some code
char* pName = foo();
...
  Code using pName
...
bar();

And just to repeat: Use of data segment, stack, heap are the common way an implementation stores variables/objects but the standard doesn't specify that it has to be done like that. The standard doesn't even mention e.g. stack and heap.

Officially, what you are asking is compiler specific. A C compiler does not have to allocate variables on the stack. In the usual case:
You say

int x = 20 ;

but you don't say where you have that

int x = 20 ;
main ()
{
int x = 20 ;
}

Generally do two different things.
The first usually causes the compiler to create a writeable, statically allocated memory area.
The second may or may not even allocate memory. The compiler can assign a CPU register to x so there is no memory for x.
X would generally be allocated on the stack but a compiler on a weird system could do it in heap as well.
You should try generating an assembly language listing to see what your compiler is doing. It will be something along the lines of
SUBL2 4, SP      ; Allocate 4 bytes ot stack
MOVL  #20, (SP)  ; initialize with the value 20

